# How can I use ext:CheckColumn in gridpanel with Linq2Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, ext.net

I just want to bind the data in a gridpanel which uses CheckColumn. The checkboxes need to be checked if 'true' and unchecked if 'false'. I don't know how to do this. I need your help. Please I need a simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U dont need to do any special thing.just decribe the colum as a CheckColumn and bind data ,here is the simple example

```
<ext:GridPanel runat="server" ID="grd" Height="300" Layout="FitLayout">

            <Store>
                <ext:Store runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="data0"></ext:ModelField>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="data1"></ext:ModelField>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="data2"></ext:ModelField>
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>

                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
            <ColumnModel>

                <Columns>
                    <ext:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" DataIndex="data0" Text="data0"></ext:Column>
                    <ext:Column ID="Column2" runat="server" DataIndex="data1" Text="data1"></ext:Column>
                    <ext:CheckColumn runat="server" DataIndex="data2" Text="data2"></ext:CheckColumn>
                </Columns>
            </ColumnModel>
        </ext:GridPanel>
```

and code behind;

```
   public partial class TestCase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //grd.GetStore().DataSource = GetData();
            //grd.DataBind(); //OR with linq,
            var Linqdata = from dt in GetData() select dt;
            grd.GetStore().DataSource = Linqdata;
            grd.DataBind();

        }


        private object[] GetData()
        {

            return new object[] { 
                new object[] { "test1", "test1", true },
                new object[] { "test2", "test2", false },
                new object[] { "test3", "test3", false } };

        }
    }
```